# How can I get a list of replies to Teams channel messages from within a logic app?

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps

I see that the Microsoft Teams connector can get me a list of channel messages, but it only retrieves the top-level messages, and not their replies. Currently, the thought process is to get this list of top-level messages and iterate through them, and to call MS Graph API to try and get their responses.

How can I get these replies? The connector does not seem to have an option to get the replies to these top-level messages. When I try to send an HTTP request to MS Graph API using our app's credentials, I get an error stating that reading messages is a protected API.

Am I able to send an HTTP request using the existing Teams API connection in our resource group? How would I go about getting these replies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of now, there is no direct connector to get the list of replies of teams channel messages. One of the workaround is to use HTTP connector with Graph API.

**Step-1** :- Register your Application then get the client id, tenant id and secret id.

[image]

[image]

**step-2** :- Navigate to **API permissions >> Add a permission >> select Microsoft Graph** and Grant access to the Graph API with ***Team.ReadBasic.All***, ***Channel.ReadBasic.All***, and ***ChannelMessage.Read.All*** permissions.

[image]

**step-3** :- As certain of the Microsoft Graph APIs are protected, you must first [raise a request](https://forms.office.com/pages/responsepage.aspx?id=v4j5cvGGr0GRqy180BHbR1ax4zKyZjVBmutzKVo1pVtUQk1YRTc3UkZRUEdRME8yR0szNEExV1VTWiQlQCN0PWcu) for access to Microsoft.

[image]

**step-4** :- After receiving the approval mail after, you are good to set up the logic app HTTP connector.

[image]

**NOTE:-** Withou approval you might be facing with `Missing role permissions on the request. API requires one of 'ChannelMessage.Read.All, ChannelMessage.Read.Group'. Roles on the request ''. Resource specific consent grants on the request ''."`

**REFERENCES:**

1. [List channel messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
2. [Get Replies to Teams Thread](https://blog.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/paulnieuwelaar/2021/05/19/get-replies-to-teams-thread-in-power-automate-with-graph-api)